# VBA Email Loop to send a report in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, loops, email, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Please help I've been struggling with this for a week now.

There’s a report I run in Microsoft Access,I’m trying to create a button that will send 8 reports to 8 different people without me having to click send (or edit the messages).
I created a form from a query with the 8 references(ADC) and Email Addresses that I am referencing to in my code, which I've attached below.
My main issues right now are:

> 1. It is still opening the message to Edit when I've input "False" in the DoCmd.
> 2. Linking the corresponding ADC Report to the right email.

```
Private Sub loop_email_Click()


DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frm_Looper", View:=acNormal, DataMode:=acFormPropertySettings, WindowMode:=acWindowNormal

Dim Email, ADC

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
'Forms!frm_Looper![ADC]

Set Email = Forms!frm_Looper!EmailAddress
Set ADC = Forms!frm_Looper!ADC

 DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Report2", acFormatPDF, Email, , , "Quarterback Report " & ADC, "Please do not reply to this address. Automated.", False
  'MsgBox "you successfully sent the last report", vbOKOnly, ""
' now go into the looper

Do While ADC > 1
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious


        'MsgBox "you should be at the previous record", vbOKOnly, ""
      Set Email = Forms!frm_Looper!EmailAddress
Set ADC = Forms!frm_Looper!ADC

 DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Report2", acFormatPDF, Email, , , "Quarterback Report " & ADC, "Please do not reply to this address. Automated.", False
  'MsgBox "you successfully sent the last report", vbOKOnly, ""
' now go into the looper

Loop
'MsgBox "Made it through the loop.", vbOKOnly, ""
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. My emails send without opening Outlook editor. However, I do get a warning popup. Look at your Outlook Trust Center > Programmatic Access setting.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @June7 In the Programmatic Access setting it doesn't allow me to change the setting, the current setting is "Warn me about suspicious activity when my antivirus software is inactive or out-of-date (recommended)". Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like the below, and putting it in to a loop? This also sends the email without opening the outlook editor:

```
''''''''''''''
' Send Email '
''''''''''''''

email = User & "@123.com"
strItem = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"
strFrom = "TestEmail@email.com"
strCC = ""

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

With objEmail
    .To = email
    .From = strFrom
    .CC = strCC
    .Subject = "Report Confirmation"
    .textbody = "Hi " & FirstName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
                "Your Voice!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

With .Configuration.Fields
        .Item(strItem & "sendusing") = 2
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserver") = "mailhost"
        .Item(strItem & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .Update
    End With
    .Send
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```